# Push notification need to open a specific activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

On the Android app, I need to open a specific activity on clicking push notification. I am directly sending the message from the firebase FCM console. I Did the configuration below, with some condition to open different activities. It is working properly while the app is in the foreground.

While the app is in the foreground, on clicking the received notification, it opens the corresponding activity based on given condition. Everything working fine.

But while the app is in the background, on clicking push notification, it opens the main activity. Also, the message showing is the message I gave in the Notification payload of FCM(Not that given in data payload/Additional section of FCM console).

I need app to open specific activity on clicking push notification while the app is in the background as well.

Can't I do this from the FCM console directly?

please advise

```java
public class MyFireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    private static int count = 0;
        
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e(TAG, "onNewToken: " + s);
    }
        
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String,String> opendata = remoteMessage.getData();
        String actionValue = opendata.get("openactivity");
        
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        assert actionValue != null;
        switch (actionValue) {
            case "Activity1":
                intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
                break;
            case "Activity2":
                intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
                break;
        }
        
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("pushnotification","True");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("MyID", "Myapp", importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyID");
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.maft_logo))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD600"))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setChannelId("Myid")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);
        
        mNotifyManager.notify(count, mBuilder.build());
        count++;
    }
}
```

Manifest

```xml
<service
    android:name=".MyFireBaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Did you fire notifications from firebase console or your backend ?

Comment: @webaddicted it is from firebase console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If notification clicks on app background state, then that will open app launcher activity. In launcher activity you need to check if there is any pending intent from notification and execute that.

Try this in your launcher activity(**MainActivity**).

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
Intent fromIntent = getIntent();
if (fromIntent.getExtras()!=null){
    try {
    Map<String,String> opendata = remoteMessage.getData();
    String actionValue = opendata.get("openactivity");

    switch (actionValue){

            case "Activity1":
                intent=new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
                break;
            case "Activity2":
                intent=new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
                break;
            default: 
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DefaultActivity.class);
                break

    }
    } catch(Exception e){
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DefaultActivity.class);
    }
} else{
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DefaultActivity.class);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.its working fine now. i haven't used below part , because showing syntax error. still its working                                                                                                       } catch(Exception e){
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DefaultActivity.class);
            }
        } else{
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DefaultActivity.class);
        }

Answer (score 1):

when your app in background, the method `onMessageReceived` never invoked, system notification auto show on your notification tray instead, so you need implement some logic (same in `onMessageReceived` method) in your main activity to navigate user to the destination screen.

Comment: should i create a onMessageReceived in the main/launcher activity?

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of notification :

1. Data message notification  other one is
2. Normal notification

In **Data message** notification send from server, when your app is kill then we got payload in onMessageReceive method.
But in case of Notification fire from other like console and your app is kill then you got default notification there is no callback in **onMessageReceive** method.

For testing you can set log in your onMessageReceive method but your log not print, when your app is kill and you fire notification from console, but with server because of data message
you got callback in onMessageReceive.

In your case everything working fine, you have to try with **actual server**.

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered that almost everything about the notification is **managed** by the cloud messaging function. You don't need to create a **NotificationManager** inside the onMessageReceived. The function presets the title & body. It can also set the activity to be opened when the notification is clicked.

You just need to include the payload parameter "click_action" that is sent alongside the notification. Your payload needs to look something like this:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
        topicId,
        {
            notification: {
                title: "Custom title",
                body:   "Custom body",
                click_action: "DestinationActivity"
            }, 
            data: {
                "payload": myPayload
            }
        }
```

More on cloud functions [here](https://medium.com/@jullainc/firebase-push-notifications-to-mobile-devices-using-nodejs-7d514e10dd4).

Now move to your project's Manifest and find the destination activity. Make the following changes (make sure to set the exported attribute to true):

```
        <activity
            android:name="DestinationActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="DestinationActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

The intent filter picks the click_action parameter from the payload so any notification with "DestinationActivity" as its click action shall be handled by the Destination activity. I am starting to think that one doesn't even need to override the onMessageReceived method. FCM makes it really convenient.